# INDEX and MATCH

Tags: if-statement, indexing, match, vlookup

Hi im looking to for help!

IF column A matches column B AND at the same time if column C matches column D;  Then return the difference from column E to F and place number in  column G

can anyone please help?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here. What language are you programming in? Where is the code sample of what you have tried so far but is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Please try in G1:

```
=IF(AND(A1=B1,C1=D1),F1-E1,"")
```

copied down to suit.